# Stubbing string hash for value instead of using dot operator in rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a unit test where I was stubbing `place.ext_fb_place_id` using

```
let(:place) { stub(:place, ext_fb_place_id: SecureRandom.random_number(20_000_000), facebook_metadata: {category: nil}, lat: 33.129147303422, lng: -96.653188420995, name: "In & Out Burger") }
```

I had to change my code to use the string key instead of the dot operator. That is, I had to use `place["ext_fb_place_id']` to get the correct value. However, this throws the following error:

```
Stub :place received unexpected message :[] with ("ext_fb_place_id")
```

How do I stub the [] method so that I can use calls like `place["ext_fb_place_id"]` or `place["lat"]`?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `stub(:[], ...)`?

Comment: Lee is correct, use :[] (and :[]= if you need that as well). @LeeJarvis, you should expand that into an answer so it can be accepted and voted on :)

Comment: @LeeJarvis Can you expand? I've tried using `stub(:[],  ext_fb_place_id: SecureRandom.random_number(20_000_000))`, but I'm having some trouble stubbing the strings inside the bracket.

Comment: @LeeJarvis Thanks for the hlp. I was able to get it. If you want to answer the question, I'd be more than happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to stub with the following:

```
ext_fb_place_id = SecureRandom.random_number(20_000_000)

let(:place) { stub(:place, ext_fb_place_id: ext_fb_place_id, facebook_metadata: {category: nil}, lat: 33.129147303422, lng: -96.653188420995, name: "In & Out Burger", :[] => ext_fb_place_id)}
```

Thanks to @LeeJarvis and @JimDeville.